# Skype calls at scheduled times to my mobile phone

Tags: skype, scheduled-tasks

I want to automate Skype to call my mobile phone at scheduled times.

Sometimes when I'm working with very complicated (business) clients, I would like an escape plan if the meeting goes over an allotted maximum time. I want to be able to say, "Hey, please call me at XX:XX" and use the automated Skype call as a good excuse to leave.

How do I set up a scheduled automatic Skype from my desktop computer to call my mobile? It just needs to call my phone, it doesn't have to make sense. I just need the call to interrupt my meeting so I can make theatre and leave.

Answer (score 2):

If you are a windows user, you can use [Windows Task Scheduler](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/308569) to execute this command:

```
"c:\Program Files\Skype\Phone\Skype.exe" /callto:+nnnnnnnn
```

`nnnnnnnn` is your country code /area code / phone number

The first time it'll prompt you to confirm, you can check the box "Do not ask again".

Works regardless if Skype is running.

Comment: how can you do this on mac os x lion?

Answer (score 2):

You could also try [Get me out of here](http://www.getmooh.com/).

Answer (score 1):

For Mac, see http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20051103212758617

`osascript -l AppleScript -e "tell application \"Skype\" to get URL \"callto://$1\""`

Answer (score 0):

For those using Windows 10 and a 64 bit OS, your default path will be different.

The following command should work:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Skype\Phone\Skype.exe" /callto:+nnnnnnnn
```

Everything else is as O.K.W has posted above.